# Creating a class in java

Tags: java

When creating a class in Java, which statements about constructors are true:

Pick 2 of these options that are correct:

**a.** A default no argument constructor is provided if you do not explicitly define any constructors for your class

**b.** The return type for a no argument constructor that you must define must be void

**c.** Every class must have at least 1 constructor

**d.** You cannot explicitly define the no argument constructor

**e.** You must define a no argument constructor if you define a constructor that accepts arguments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels a final class is just what it says. `final class MyClass{...}`

Comment: http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140120172632AA5YHP0

Comment: yikes, I stand corrected. Brain fart.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Honestly, I was on your side. The questions have nothing to do with a class declared `final`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework question.  Looks like a cut & paste from a multiple choice quiz.

Comment: Are you sitting in an exam at the moment, using a mobile device to post this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a trick question because the answer is not specifically related to a final class but any class.

So,

```
a. a default no argument constructor is provided if you do not explicitly define any constructors for your class

c. every class must have at least 1 constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

a and c

The keyword final used in this question is not needed.  A final class is no different than any other class in java except that you can not extend it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option (a)** a default no argument constructor is provided for you if you do not specify one is true.

> #### [JLS 8.8.9 Default Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)
>
> If a `class` contains no constructor declarations, then a *default constructor* that takes no parameters is automatically provided:
>
> - if the `class` is declared `public`, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier `public`;
> - if the class is declared `protected`, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier `protected`;
> - if the class is declared `private`, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier `private`;
> - otherwise, the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier.

**Option (c)** is true, every class must have at least 1 constructor. Remember that the default constructor will be provided if you do not specify one. Therefore, every class has at least one.